How to use st.file_uploader() returned object to parse pdf through LlamaParse() in python streamlit?
I am trying to upload a PDF using st.file_uploader() from streamlit and then parse it using LlamaParse() currently running on localhost.
Issue is I am getting [] in output which is probably happening because of directly using returned uploaded_file from the below code.
I am not sure if a returned uploaded object can directly be used to feed llama_parse as this PDF works when I directly upload the PDF from my local machine directory into LlamaParse() instead of uploaded_file = st.file_uploader()
Is there something that I need to do for using uploaded_file before feeding it into LlamaParse()?

Setting up streamlit:
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

import os
import nest_asyncio 

nest_asyncio.apply()
os.environ["LLMA_CLOUD_API_KEY"] = "my_key"
key_input = "my_key"

from llama_parse import LlamaParse

############### Setting Configuration ###############

st.set_page_config(page_title="Pdf Parsing",
                    layout='wide',
                    initial_sidebar_state="expanded")

# title
st.markdown("<h1 style='text-align: center; font-size: 70px;color: black;letter-spacing: 4px;'>PDF Parsing</h1>", unsafe_allow_html=True)


Uploading file & parsing through Llama:
st.write("checkpoint1")
with st.container(border=True):

    st.write("checkpoint2")
    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader('Choose your .pdf file to upload', type="pdf")


    if uploaded_file is not None:
        st.write(uploaded_file.name)
        st.success("File is uploaded")

if uploaded_file:
    if st.button('Parse Uploaded pdf file (Powered by AI)'):

        doc_parsed = LlamaParse(result_type="markdown",api_key=key_input
                                ).load_data(uploaded_file)

        st.write('checkpoint3')
        st.write(doc_parsed)




UPDATE:
Is this happening Due to Not Using st.session_state ?
Could it be a possibility that when I click the button then the whole app refreshes/runs again and the file gets lost and nothing goes into llama ?

I think the issue is that it requires file in .pdf format so when I am passing the variable/object instead of .pdf then it doesn't work. May be if I host this anywhere then first I need to save the uploaded file and then give that path to the llamaParse

The issues is not because of st.file_uploader but because of llamaParse()
Adding file_name in , extra_info makes llamaParse to run with uploaded file within streamlit.
below code works:
doc_parsed = LlamaParse(result_type="markdown",api_key=key_input,
                                parsing_instruction=parsingInstruction
                            ).load_data(st.session_state.uploaded_file.getvalue(), 
                                        extra_info={"file_name": "_"})

More info: Streamlit discussion post
